# What is wrong with my function that accepts an array of 2 element and check if the first element has every letter in the second element?

Tags: javascript

The function is given an array of 2 elements, 2 string to be exact. If the first element has every single letter in the second element (just one time, no case, no order), then the function returns true, if not false.

hey and hello works. But for example, mutation(["zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba", "qrstu"]) is not returning true, somehow. I suspect there is something wrong with my if statement nested inside my for loop. Am I returning false or true multiple times, or some other problem?

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  var one=arr[0];
  var two=arr[1];
  
  one.toLowerCase();
  two.toLowerCase();
  
  var array=two.split("");
  
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(one.indexOf(array[i]) !== -1){
      return false;
    }else return true;
  }
  
  
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

EDIT:
New discovery! if I move else return true to right after the end bracket of the for loop, mutation("hello", "neo") would return false, as wanted. But if I did that, then, mutation("hello", "hey") wouldn't return true, whereas before the change, it would.

Comment: You can't "return multiple times".  Once a value is returned, it's returned.  The function is done executing at that point.  When you step through this code in a debugger, where does the behavior differ from what you expect?  What are the values of the variables when that happens?

Comment: David is right, you have return inside a for loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  if(one.indexOf(array[i]) !== -1){
    return false;
  }else return true;
}
```

is essentially (close enough) the same as this:

```
if(one.indexOf(array[0]) !== -1){
  return false;
}else return true;
```

That is, you're not actually looping over anything.  Because, no matter what, your loop always returns on the *first* iteration.

Consider the logic of what your function should do.  If I understand correctly, you want to return false if the loop ever encounters a letter that isn't found in `one`.  And to return true if the loop *never* encounters such a match.  In that case, the default condition *after* the loop would be to return true.  Something like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  if(one.indexOf(array[i]) === -1){
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

Basically, if the loop never found a "non-match", then it never returned false.  So return true.

**Edit:** I also changed the comparison in the `if`, because I think you had it reversed.  But I guess I'm not 100% sure on that, since the intent of the method is a little unclear.  (The logic therein is a bit confusing, and the name of the method certainly doesn't help.)  But hopefully you at least get the idea and can test/validate accordingly for your needs.

Comment: Yes its is reverse. A very stupid mistake. I am very impatient. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I got it now. That solve the problem. Btw, should be one=one.toLowerCase(); And that is it!

Comment: Good example that illustrates the problem with the loop.  However the logic of the code fails to meet the conditions described in the question.  The function as provided in the original question finds if all of the second string's characters are in the first,rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should only return false if you find any character in `one` that wasn't in `two`, but you can only return true at the end of the loop, because then you know all characters match.  It can't be in the else block.

Second, Shouldn't it be the other way around based on your description?  You should iterate the characters of `one` and see if they are in `two` instead.  Then it would fit.

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  var one=arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var two=arr[1].toLowerCase();

  var oneArr=one.split("");
  var twoArr=two.split("");
  
  console.log("Do all of '" + one + "' characters occur in '" + two + "'?");

  for(var i=0;i<oneArr.length;i++){
    console.log("Looking for " + oneArr[i]);

    // If any characters in two didn't occur in one, it fails
    var twoIndex = twoArr.indexOf(oneArr[i]);
    if(twoIndex === -1) {
      console.log("Can't find " + oneArr[i]);
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log("Found at index " + twoIndex + " in '" + two + "'");
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(mutation(["hey", "hello"]));

console.log(mutation(["qrstu", "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"]));
```

Comment: So the change is that you remove ! and move return true outside of the loop. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, this was your programming issue.  In your question you say you need all the characters in the first word to be in the second word.  But in your code its the other way around, it checks that all the second characters are in the first word.  See my code for that change.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you're using an else block to return true inside the loop, so your loop is only checking one element then either returning true or false based on whether or not that element is in the first string. Put the return true statement after the for loop.

The second issue is that when you're checking for existence, you're returning false *if it does exist*. Use `one.indexOf(array[i]) === -1` instead.

The final issue is that you're splitting a string to iterate it, but strings don't need to be split to be iterated using a for loop.

The rest of the changes just use less lines of code to do the same thing.

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  arr = arr.map(e => e.toLowerCase());
  
  for(let i = arr[1].length - 1; i > -1; --i)
    if(arr[0].indexOf(arr[1][i]) === -1) return false;
  
  return true;
}

console.log(mutation(["hello", "hey"]));
console.log(mutation(["hello", "hel"]));
console.log(mutation(["zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba", "qrstu"]));
```